# Navigation buttons send me to arbitrary parts of the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I click my `contact us page button` it takes me to the end of the contact page in my footer and I don't know why.

Also when I click on one of my links in my navigation bar or when I refresh my page I am at the place where I was census on the page (a section, or any other div of my page but not at the beginning)

I want the button to direct me to the page and to the top of my contact page.

```html
<button type="button" className="items-center w-max rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-7 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"> 
    <Link to="contact"> Send </Link> 
</button>
```

Comment: You need to show the code so we can take a look and analyze what is wrong.

Comment: <button type="button" className="items-center w-max rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-7 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600">
            <Link to="contact"> Send </Link> 
            </button>

Comment: It could be the code in your `contact` or `footer` component which caused it to focus into these component instead of navigation at the top of the page

Comment: I always have the same problem when I click on the button the focus of the page is done in the centre of the page please help me I am a beginner in react